# Send event from external js file to Vuejs component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, data-binding, signalr

How can I send events from an external js file to Vue components?
i use signalR in external file and i want to get data when come from api runtime but when get data can't send it to vue

this is js file :

```js
import { HubConnectionBuilder } from "@microsoft/signalr";
let connection;

export const ReceiveMessagePrivate = () => {
  var dataJson;
  connection.on(
    "ReceiveMessagePrivate",
    (GroupGuid, UserGuid, UserName, MessageGuid, MessageText, TimeString, FileName, FileType) => {
      dataJson = {
        GroupGuid: GroupGuid,
        UserGuid: UserGuid,
        UserName: UserName,
        MessageGuid: MessageGuid,
        MessageText: MessageText,
        TimeString: TimeString,
        FileName: FileName,
        FileType: FileType
      };
    }
    return dataJson
  );
};
```

vue file component :

```
import * as userHub from "../userHub";
export default {

  created() {
    consol.log(userHub.ReceiveMessagePrivate());
  },

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it run when i use **eventBus**

js file :

```js
import { HubConnectionBuilder } from "@microsoft/signalr";
import Vue from "vue";
let connection;
export const eventBus = new Vue();

export const ReceiveMessagePrivate = () => {
  var dataJson;
  connection.on(
    "ReceiveMessagePrivate",
    (GroupGuid, UserGuid, UserName, MessageGuid, MessageText, TimeString, FileName, FileType) => {
      dataJson = {
        GroupGuid: GroupGuid,
        UserGuid: UserGuid,
        UserName: UserName,
        MessageGuid: MessageGuid,
        MessageText: MessageText,
        TimeString: TimeString,
        FileName: FileName,
        FileType: FileType
      };
      eventBus.$emit("recMesPri", dataJson);
    }
  );
};
```

vue file :

```
import * as userHub from "../userHub";
export default {
.
.
.
  created() {
    userHub.ReceiveMessagePrivate();
    userHub.eventBus.$on("recMesPri", (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    });
  },
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I confirm the event bus is suitable for this use case. In addition, it would be good to unsubscribe your listener each time the vue component is destroyed, because a new listener is added each time the vue component is created:

```
created() {
  userHub.ReceiveMessagePrivate();
  userHub.eventBus.$on("recMesPri", this.handler);
},
beforeDestroy() {
  userHub.eventBus.$off("recMesPri", this.handler);
},
methods: {
  handler(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
},
```